# Adding metadata tags to jsTree nodes?

Tags: javascript, tags, jstree

I have a [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) that I have rendered and is being generated by JSON from a Java REST endpoint.

Each node (there are about 5 levels) will have a few tags associated with it. I'll grab the tags from the java endpoint but right now I'm trying to come up with a proof of concept of how I can show it.

I would prefer the tags show up in a list, next to each node since there will only be a few. 
I was looking at [jQuery Tag-it!](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) as a possibility. The tags will be read only.

How could I display them next to each node? I don't even know where to start with that...

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood right but if you want to display the "metadata tags" you can you [jsTree grid](https://github.com/deitch/jstree-grid)

Comment: Similar to how each Stack Overflow post has tags associated, each node will have tags associated with it that will be retrieved by my AJAX call as JSON, I just need to display it.

Comment: Did you check jsTree Grid? How do you want to display it?

Comment: Each node in the tree will have a small list of tags right next to it. I haven't seen any pictures of jsTree Grid to see if that is what I want to use.

Comment: I've been exploring and jsTree Grid works very well. I have a question about it though, I'll make a new post and link it here.

Comment: I made two posts. The first one is very important but the other one isn't a HUGE priority like the first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980044/i-am-using-jstree-and-jstree-grid-and-data-in-my-second-column-disppears  I would be glad to offer a bounty of my reputation for your help.

Comment: Here is the second: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979793/defining-the-column-width-to-automatic-in-jstree-grid