# I am using jsTree and jsTree Grid and data in my second column disppears

Tags: javascript, html, jstree

I have one column in jsTree Grid representing my tree. The second column is used for displaying "tags" associated with each node. It is displaying great until I click another level.

So the second column will create a div and my tags (similar to stack overflow tags) are appended to that html element.

Here is the issue, when the page first loads. I see the root node just fine and the "tags" associated with the root node that I defined in the second column. Looks great!

When I click to expand the root node, to get to the next level. I lose the tags associated with the root node. What I want is to keep them but I can't figure out why the grid is losing it.

EDIT:

Removed the code and images.

Comment: Can you give us a more complete example of the json data?

Comment: I added another function to this post to show how my JSON is getting called from the server and manipulated into another form of JSON for the tree. mapNameTag is exclusively to represent the "tags" I have next to each node in the second column. It could comma separated value list and it would be displayed as tags.

Comment: I am not looking the Grid values when I go to deeper level ... http://jsfiddle.net/radek/4fTDq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the jsTreeGrid plugin redraws the cells when you expand a node. Since you only append your tags during the "loaded" and "select_cell" events, the tags disappear.

You can workaround this by re-appending the tags on more events:

```
.bind("open_node.jstree create_node.jstree clean_node.jstree change_node.jstree", function (event, data) { 
    doDisplayTags(mapNameTag);
})
```